# Don't show button chrome/skin/visual style except on hover?

Tags: c#, winforms

Whenever form buttons are created in C#, they come by default with the visual style for buttons of that operating system. What I'm trying to do is this: by default, only show the text or icon of a button. When the text and/or icon is hovered over, also show the rest of the button's visual style that we hid before.

Does that make any sense? Does anyone know how this might be accomplished? I've seen it done before, but I'm not sure how it's done.

I should clarify - I'm not using WPF, or XAML.

Comment: please add more tags... or at least be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `Style` and a `ControlTemplate` and hide the `ControlTemplate` when the mouse is over.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WpfApplication8" Height="200" Width="200" Name="mainWindow" >

    <Window.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="dummyStyle" >
            <Border>
                <ContentPresenter Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="masterStyle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource dummyStyle}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource masterStyle}" Content="Button" Height="44" Width="129" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

If your using winforms (not sure) you could make a simple custom control, something like this:

```
public partial class HoverButton : UserControl
{
    private string _buttonText;

    public HoverButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ButtonText = "HoverButton1";
    }

    public string ButtonText
    {
        get { return _buttonText; }
        set
        { 
            _buttonText = value;
            button1.Text = _buttonText;
            label1.Text = _buttonText;
        }
    }


    private void label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
    }
}

partial class HoverButton
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_MouseLeave);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label1.Text = "label1";
        this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.label1.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_MouseEnter);
        // 
        // HoverButton
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "HoverButton";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
}
```

Comment: That would be a great option if I were using WPF for this particular project, but I'm not. :/

Comment: could you elaborate on what framework your are actually using?

Comment: added winforms example incase you are using winforms

Comment: The Winforms example is neat, but doesn't take into account button icons. I guess there isn't a way to do this without creating a button under an image and text, and hiding that button?

Comment: Button does have an `Image` property, you will just have to add acessors to your custom control, (I do not miss winforms at all , LOL)